# symbolic constants

Tags: c

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#define abc 7

int main()
{

int abc=1;

printf("%d",abc);

getch();

return 0;
}
```

why this program is giving compile time error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're assigning `7=1` which is invalid. Since you've defined `abc` to be 7, the preprocessor translates the line:

```
int abc=1;
```

to:

```
int 7=1;
```

Which is a syntax error in C (my `gcc` says *syntax error before numeric constant*).

Answer (score 2):

You define `abc` as `7`.

Then `int abc=1` is transformed into `int 7=1` which is absurd.

*Why* are you doing this?

Answer (score 2):

> You declare "abc" macro value as 7 .
>   So if again include the macro name as
>   variable, it will give error.

consider the following

> abc value is 7. So it will treated
>   as 7=1. So that it will give error.

Answer (score 0):

The C preprocessor does a blind replacement of `abc` with `7` resulting in:

```
int 7=1;
```

which clearly is an error.

Answer (score 0):

When the preprocessor replaces `abc` with `7`, the following line becomes invalid:

```
int 7=1;
```

An identifier in C, can't be just a number.